# Change the Facebook SDK 3.0 Loggin Button Image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm integrating the facebook SDK 3.0 into my application, I've add the facebook login button to may layout, can someone help me how can i change facebook login button with my custom image

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFF"
              android:id="@+id/main_ui_container">
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
            />
<LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do I understand rightly that you'ved added Facebook's own custom FacebookLoginButton view?

If that's the case, then the constructor `FacebookLoginButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)` will be called by the layout inflator, which references the R file of the facebook library- no good.

So if you want to customize that button beyond what is exposed in the facebook sdk, I've had success with copying the view class - FacebookLoginButton.java - into my own project (you may need to tinker with FacebookLoginButton.java to make sure everything references back to the facebook library correctly). Along with it, copy *all* of the resources referenced by that constructor into your *own* project. It goes without saying, you'll now need to make sure everything in the copied class references your projects resources now.

Finally, you'll of course need to change the button class in your layout file to the fully qualified class name to that copied FacebookLoginButton in your own project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated the question,I've used the login button provide by the facebook SDK 3.0, i want to change the default icon of that? do i need to copy the facebookLoginButton and required resource to change the image of the loginButton

Comment: We use SDK 3.0 too. Ming Li's answer is what it really should be, but open up the SDK 3.0 and look at thyat FacebookLoginButton class. Then cast your eye to about line 240:     this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_facebook..._blue);. Strictly speaking, this should block you from setting your own background resource, AFAIK. So nick the class, and the required resources, and then just change that one line to reference your own drawable. As in our case, it's worth the hassle just because there may be other things you want to change later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just specify the android:background for the LoginButton in your layout.

See the Friend Smash sample, which uses a customized background for the LoginButton.

https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this elements of the button:

```
<declare-styleable name="com_facebook_login_view">
    <attr name="confirm_logout" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="fetch_user_info" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="login_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="logout_text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

using those attributes in the xml. You can also define a style and change everything related to the button.